# Next.js and Asp.Net Core Web API - DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Tags: ssl, next.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Asp.net Core Web API as backend and Next.js as frontend.

API runs on the localhost using a self-signed SSL. It is https.

Next.js also runs on the localhost but it doesn't have a SSL. It is just http.

Before connecting to API from Next.js, I connected to the endpoints on browser. And they work perfectly. When I try to connect them on Postman, it says "SSL Error: Unable to verify the first certificate" and it shows a "disable SSL verification" button. When I click it, it's also works.

But when I try to connect it from my Next.js app, I have "TypeError: fetch failed" error on browser and on the console of VS Code shows:

```
cause: Error: self-signed certificate
     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
     at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
   code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
  }
```

So what causes the problem? Is it about API or frontend? How should I handle the local SSL certificate problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can [setting the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable to `0` in your development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35633993/7687666). This approach is not recommended for production environments due to security risks.

And we also could add the self-signed certificate as a trusted CA. [NextJS + HTTPS | For a Local Dev Server](https://medium.com/@greg.farrow1/nextjs-https-for-a-local-dev-server-98bb441eabd7)